# New Strong Probable Prime testing method

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if $n$ is a strong probable to base $a$, then assuming $n$ is not a multiple $2$ or $3$:

$n$ $=$ $1$ $\mod 3$, then:

$a^{(n-1)/3}$ = $y$ $\mod n$

and

$y^3$ = $1$ $\mod n$

or

$n$ $=$ $2$ $\mod 3$, then:

$a^{(n+1)/3}$ = $y$ $\mod n$

and

$y^3$ = $a^2$ $\mod n$

and that this is true for all primes $>$ $3$.

Comment: it is the definition of pseudo-prime in base $a$ and of the Fermat theorem

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\left(a^{(n-1)/3}\right)^3=a^{n-1}$ and $\left(a^{(n+1)/3}\right)^3=a^{n+1}$ and use the fact that $\gcd(a,n)=1.$